# linux wget not certified?

Tags: linux, ssl, wget

I'm trying to do a simple wget on my server that's brand new and I'm getting this error.  I've never encountered anything like this - at all...

```
[root@ip-219-140 ~]# wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455970/litecoin-0.6.3c-linux.tar.gz
--10:11:52--  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455970/litecoin-0.6.3c-linux.tar.gz
Resolving dl.dropboxusercontent.com... 54.243.119.191
Connecting to dl.dropboxusercontent.com|54.243.119.191|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify dl.dropboxusercontent.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to dl.dropboxusercontent.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: Do you only need this for dropbox? And which linux distribution it is? If you don't know, please show output of `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions:

> To connect to dl.dropboxusercontent.com insecurely,  use
>   `--no-check-certificate'.

Run:

```
 wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455970/litecoin-0.6.3c-linux.tar.gz
```

it worked for me just fine!

Comment: But this is still not very good solution - now anybody who spoofs your DNS (relatively easy to do), can fool you into uploading/downloading to fake server, or simply steal your password

Comment: @mvp it's dropbox and the content is under the `public` folder so you can d/l it alright, but you can't mess with it and definitely can't upload without having the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the underlying problem instead of "--no-check-certificate".

On some Ubuntu versions (14.04 server for sure) wget and openssl are compiled with default CA store in /usr/lib/ssl/certs instead of /etc/ssl/certs where actually certs are present.

Fixed by symlink:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/ssl
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs /usr/lib/ssl/certs
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates

 sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Solution 2:
Create **~/.wgetrc** file and add to it:

```
ca_certificate=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```