# Download build files from Nexus, certificate error when running wget, but succeed with browser (Firefox, Chrome)

Tags: ssl, certificate, wget, nexus

I've already purchased the SSL Certifcate from DigiCert and install it into my Nexus server (running in tomcat, jks)

It works well in firefox and chrome(green address bar indicates that a valid certificate received) , builds could be downloaded from Nexus WebUI too.

But, **wget** could not get the result without --no-check-certificate
something like

```
ERROR: cannot verify mydomain.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to mydomain.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Found something,

[SSL connection fails with wget, curl, but succeed with firefox and lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986195/ssl-connection-fails-with-wget-curl-but-succeed-with-firefox-and-lynx/25986318#25986318)

[linux wget not certified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328157/linux-wget-not-certified)

But neither of them gives a final solution, I want to know whether there are some (special) configurations on Nexus or this's a bug of wget command?

Google return many results about "digitcert wget",but I cannot find a clue either, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the DigiCert root certificate to a store accessible by wget:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wget-ssl-certs

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I have to add certificate on client which runs wget, but what you said have hint me to check the certificate chains on Nexus server.